# Compile Matlab generated C source code on a Linux platform to created a Linux MEX

Tags: matlab, mex

I have a Windows Matlab R2020a and was able to generate C source code for my Matlab function. However, I need to run a MEX file (for speed) on a Linux platform which has a Matlab installed (without Coder) and no way to install it (even trial version).

Please, provide the steps to compile this Matlab-generated C code on the linux (Ubuntu) system. I guess it can be done with gcc. I am unable to find a clear description on the web, as this process seems extremely complicated due to the obscure command line args needed to give to gcc (and i only rarely compile C code).

Comment: There’s a `mex` command in MATLAB, read the docs for it to learn how to make a MEX-file.

Comment: If i understand correcly this mexFunction is some sort of interface between Matlab and the compiled executable code, to let matlab call the compiled code

Comment: @SheppLogan I've converted my comments into an answer, to ease the reading.

Comment: @SheppLogan Please, consider upvoting my answer if you find it useful in any way. Thanks.

Comment: I did it with coder on another Linux and it works in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, note that generating C code using the MATLAB Coder App is not enough if you need a `MEX` file. `MEX` files have to contain a `mexFunction` function, which is not generated by the Coder App.

As a first step, I'd make sure your compiler is supported by MATLAB for the creation of MEX files. You can find the supported compilers on Linux [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/support/requirements/supported-compilers-linux.html). Then I'd check whether the compiler is setup for Matlab to use it, as shown [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-default-compiler.html). Finally, I'd have a look at some examples provided by Mathworks themselves: [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/table-of-mex-file-source-code-files.html)

Once the `C` code (with the `mexFunction`) is ready, you can compile it using the `mex` command and use it on the Linux platform with no or minimal adjustments, depending on how heavily you rely on the functions defined in `mex.h` (which is the header your `C` file will have to import if you want to generate a `MEX` file).

You need the interface provided by the `mexFunction` for Matlab to be able to exchange inputs and outputs with the compiled function. Note that you can create other standard C functions (possibly defined in other `C` files) and call them from within the `mexFunction` as you would normally do in `C`. Basically, you can create your own libraries in `C` and then use them in Matlab via dedicated `mexFunction`s.

`mex.h` also provides the API to "convert" `C` data structures into Matlab data structures (e.g. arrays, cell arrays etc., all via the `mxArray` type).

There's a bit of a learning curve, mostly spent in understanding how to convert data back and forth between standard `C` and Matlab, but it's certainly worth your while. With a bit of care (e.g. switching to `mxArray` types only when absolutely necessary), you can end up having libraries of functions that can be used in standard `C` programs as well as in Matlab applications

Comment: its a nice answer, you seem quite knowledgeable about MEX(es)

Comment: I guess they do something similar in Python... i have to search about that too...

Comment: @SheppLogan with that username, you may want to look at how the TIGRE toolbox (coded by me, among others) do this. I use `mex` for matlab and `cython` for python.